# CISCO ISE 2.3: Endpoints not appearing in active endpoint list

Tags: cisco, cisco-ise

I have setup CISCO ISE on my local machine using Vmware by providing basic details as shown in the image.

[image]

I am able to login to ISE 2.3 using  https://10.129.86.180/admin/login.jsp.
After login, I added Shinchan endpoint to ISE through Administration -> Network Resources -> n/w devices menu.

But I am facing following issues:

1. Shichan endpoint not showing in active endpoint list
2. In Alarm : Getting log -> ISE Authetication inactivity

I don't have Radius server or TACACS for above network.

Comment: You don’t add endpoints as network devices in ISE, network devices are reserved for NADs like switches and routers to authenticate themselves or hosts onto the network. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but ISE is a NAC Server it can discover clients (through authentication or one of the profiling methods) or have them manually added but it’s not made to be an MDM solution.